In .NET MAUI application, How to access the MainActivity instance in App class
I want to use MainActivity.Instance in App class to get the height and width of the device. But in MAUI application, App class logic is executing before MainActivity class execution. So I'm getting Mainactivity.Instance as null.
Below are my classes. Please suggest
MainApplication class:
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
 {
     public MainApplication(nint handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership) : base(handle, ownership)
     {
     }

     protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
     {
         var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
         builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

         return builder.Build();
     }
}

MainActivity class:
public class MainActivity : global::Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            Instance = this;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogErrorAsync(ex);
        }
    }
}

Logic calling MainActivity.Instance in App class:
public int ScreenWidth
{
    get
    {
        var density = MainActivity.Instance.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
        return Convert.ToInt32(_screenWidth / density);
    }
}

I tried above logic but it did not work. Please suggest.

You can get the device width and height by accessing the main display info instead of accessing the MainActivity:
var width = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
var height = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height;

If you really need to access the MainActivity for some reason, you can do that anywhere in the shared code by using the Platform helpers like this:
#if ANDROID
    var activity = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
#endif

